# File content is not available after fputcsv

Tags: php, file

Please explain to me why the function `file_get_contents` returns the contents of the file, while `fread` does not. How can I read file content after `fputcsv`?

```
$file = fopen('test.txt', 'r+');
fputcsv($file, [1, 2, 4]);
var_dump(fread($file, 1024));
var_dump(file_get_contents('test.txt'));
```

Comment: After writing you need to seek to the beginning to read what you wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fread()` reads from the current position in the file stream, which is *after* what you just wrote. You need to seek to the beginning to read the file.

```
$file = fopen('test.txt', 'r+');
fputcsv($file, [1, 2, 4]);
fseek($file, 0);
var_dump(fread($file, 1024));
```